# Disable parent frame without stopping thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, modal-dialog

I'm developing a Swing app, and I need to run an infinite loop in the background (which runs until: 1) the cancel button of my JDialog is selected or 2) the input data it is searching for is found) while a modal dialog shows an indeterminate progress bar.

Something I've noticed is that if the JDialog is modal, then the SwingWorker will not execute its tasks until the JDialog is closed (and releases its deathgrip on the EDT, I guess...?). If the JDialog is not modal, then SwingWorker's tasks will execute happily in the background.

I've been doing some research, but I'm no thread/EDT expert and am having a hard time figuring the reason/solution.

Any input on this situation/threads/EDT/SwingWorker, or a suggested solution, would be greatly appreciated.

(Question pulled directly from: http://www.coderanch.com/t/346275/GUI/java/SwingWorker-Modal-JDialogs)

I tried the solution regarding the setVisible call of the JDialog like this user found to be the solution, but I still can't execute both threads simultaneously. Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant:

```
public Dialog(JFrame parentFrame, String equipmentName) {
    super(parentFrame, "Progress");

    this.hasRequestedCancel = false;
    this.equipmentName = equipmentName;

    add(createMainPanel());
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(SomeClass.class.getResource(ICON_PATH)));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    setModalityType(ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
    pack();
    setSize(550, 100);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(parentFrame);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

And

```
SwingWorker<File, Void> worker = createSwingWorker(params, ...);
worker.execute();
```

And

```
private SwingWorker<File, Void> createSwingWorker(final File someFile, final SomeClass asdf, final String param3) throws IOException {
    SwingWorker<File, Void> swingWorker = new SwingWorker<File, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected File doInBackground() throws IOException {
            Dialog progressBar = new Dialog(SomeClass.this, SomeClass.this.equipManufacturerDevice);

            try {
                while(!someFile.exists() && !progressBar.hasRequestedCancel()) {
                    Thread.sleep(SomeClass.SLEEP_DURATION);
                    System.out.println("yo");
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            ...
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            ...
        }
    };

    return swingWorker;
}
```

Comment: *"he parent frame (and the parent frame alone) houses the logic for checking for data input. If I set the JDialog with a modal ... mode, then the entire parent thread pauses."*  A modal dialog will block ***user input*** to the parent frame, but the EDT will remain unaffected, so things in the frame can still change based on changes made in a modal dialog.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: updated with some code... not sure if it'll be all that helpful though

Comment: *"updated with some code."*  If I'd thought that posting uncompilable code snippets was helpful, I would have advised to post uncompilable code snippets.  I advised to post an MCVE, and included a convenient link to explain.  Since you seem to have not followed and read the information at the link, -1.

Comment: When you use a `SwingWorker`, only the code in the method `doInBackground()` (hence the name) will be executed in a background thread. Whatever you do in the constructor will still be executed by the instantiating thread. But what is your problem with posting the entire code of your class?

Comment: The execution pathway doesn't ever seem to reach the    doInBackground() method, for some reason. I tested this by putting a simple print line statement at the beginning of the method, and it doesn't seem to be reaching this statement. As for why I can't post the entire code, it's because I don't own it. I'm helping debug for someone else, and I don't have their permission to post the entire code. Thanks for asking instead of jumping to haughty conclusions, unlike @AndrewThompson

Comment: @user2521350: that’s what I said, if you are performing a blocking operation in your `SwingWorker`’s constructor, you will get blocked right while constructing it. If you never complete its construction and hence never invoke `execute()` on it, the `doInBackground()` method will never be called.

Comment: @Holger Sorry, maybe I should've also included that I call execute() after constructing the swingworker. Of course, again, the issue is that my code seems to be halting on this call. I actually found another question on coderanch where the asker seems to articulate my/his question more clearly (http://www.coderanch.com/t/346275/GUI/java/SwingWorker-Modal-JDialogs), but his solution of calling setVisible after execution won't work for me since I'm sitting on an infinite loop, waiting for data, while the JDialog must be shown... I'm beginning to think this problem might not have a solution

Comment: @user2521350: If you understood my comment you knew that I already assumed that `execute()` is called *after* constructing the swingworker as that’s how it’s supposed to be. But if you call the blocking `setVisible(true)` *while* constructing the swingworker (or at any other point before `execute()`) that point will never be reached. What’s the problem with calling `setVisible(true)` after `execute()`? `execute()` will *return immediately* as it only triggers the *background* execution of `doInBackground()`.

Comment: @Holger The issue is that one of the conditions that breaks the infinite loop in my doInBackground() method relies on a user selecting a button from the JDialog, so I'm forced to instantiate the JDialog somewhere prior to calling execute().

I've also edited my question to include as much relevant code as I can now. Thanks for all your help so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `setVisible(true)` inside the `Dialog`’s constructor which is a discouraged practice anyway (you just found one reason, why).

Separate the creation and opening of the dialog and you don’t have that problem anymore. The following sample code demonstrates how this can be achieved:

```
final Dialog d=new Dialog((Window)null);
d.setSize(300, 300);
d.setModal(true);
new SwingWorker<Object,Object>() {
  @Override
  protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("long running stuff");
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    System.out.println("end of long running stuff");
    return null;
  }
  @Override
  protected void done() {
    d.dispose();
  }
}.execute();
System.out.println("before setVisible(true)");
d.setVisible(true);// will block
System.out.println("after setVisible(true)");
```

Comment: Yep, hit the nail on the forehead. I had no idea calling setVisible within the constructor for a GUI wasn't standard... This isn't part of the question anymore, but I was wondering if you could point me in the direction of any guides for GUI construction too? If not, thanks for your help anyways! Got it to run without issue.

Answer (score 0):

What if you moved the data input logic from the main frame and kept it running on a separate, dedicated, background thread whose sole job is to listen for connections and handle them. This would leave your parent JFrame to handle UI interactions thereby giving you the freedom to freeze it when one of your JDialog has focus.

Comment: To the type of question that is asked, this seems like a fine type of answer.

Comment: Answers are not 'better or worse' depending on the question, and should stand in their own right.  -1

Comment: A question that requests thread design opinions and contains no code, can be sufficiently answered by thread design opinions with no code.

Comment: *"A question that requests thread design opinions.."*  ..is closable even on that basis.  This is a *Question and Answer* site, not a *Discussion and Opinion* site.